# Socket connection between war file on tomcat and local file

Tags: java, c, sockets

I have a project in which I have to make socket connection between war file on tomcat (localhost:8080) and a C file runs on local system. the war file is written in spring boot. The thing is when I run the java code on IDE . It is making the socket connection. But when I deploy that as a war file on tomcat outside the IDE. Its not connecting to local C file.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "C file"? You don't make socket connections to files (except maybe Unix domain sockets), did you mean a program (which happens to be written in C)?

Comment: yes the program written in C which is on local system and Java is as a war file on tomcat.

Comment: AFAIR tomcat is some server application. Also you mention `localhost:8080` which indicates that Jave application is a server. Then you state "Is it not connecting to local C file". This should be "The local program compiled from C file cannot connect to Java application", correct?

Comment: yes local c file not connected to Java code on tomcat

Comment: After a cursory look at tomcat, it seems it has a lot of API calls available. So, if your java program works standalone, it is using standard low-level calls like (the equiv. of) `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept`, etc? If you want to run it in tomcat, don't you have to use the tomcat API calls instead?

Comment: @CraigEstey As far as I'm aware, Tomcat allows you to create normal socket connections using the Java Socket API if you want to.